# Strip portions of a string outside a character

Tags: python

The goal is to run through a list of strings, and for each index of the list, remove any exterior formatting as shown below:

Say for instance this is the given list:

```
st1 = ['apple', 'none:apple_one', 'two:apple_two:word', 'banana', 'there:banana_one:ban', 'there:bana']
```

I would like for the script to convert the list to the following format:

```
output = ['apple', 'apple_one', 'apple_two', 'banana', 'banana_one', 'there']
```

Note that any words outside the `:` are removed. For example `'two:apple_two:word' -> 'apple_two'`.

I have tried to use the `split(':')` function in a `for loop` and then sub sequentially index the `[1]` element for each string converted to a list... However this is not working for me. See below my tested code.

```
for j in st1:
    print(j)
    k = 0
    if ':' in j:
        st1[k] = j.split(':')[1]
    k += 1

    print(st1[k])

output = '\n'.join(st1)
```

From the print statement this is what I get as a return:

```
apple
none:apple_one
none:apple_one
none:apple_one
two:apple_two:word
none:apple_one
banana
none:apple_one
there:banana_one:ban
none:apple_one
there:bana
none:apple_one
```

I notice that for the number of split cases it outputs that many of that string, and I am not sure why that is... If someone could help to solve either the first issue or help with why my output is as it is that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So in the case of `a:b`, you always keep `b`, and in the case of a:b:c you also keep b?

One issue I see is that you reset `k` to 0 each loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
st1 = ['apple', 'none:apple_one', 'two:apple_two:word', 'banana', 'there:banana_one:ban', 'there:bana']

for i, val in enumerate(st1):
    if ':' in val:
        st1[i] = val.split(':')[1]

output = '\n'.join(st1)

print(output)
```

Output:

```
apple
apple_one
apple_two
banana
banana_one
bana
```

---

The issue with your current code is that you keep resetting `k` to 0 every time your loop runs.  This means that you only ever operate on your first (or index `0`) item in `st1`

---

A one line version:

```
'\n'.join(x.split(":")[1] if ":" in x else x for x in st1)
```

Comment: Works just as desired, the enumerate(st1) function is helpful as well...

Comment: Can't yet because of timer. @Julio P.C.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use `re`:

```py
import re

st1 = ['apple', 'none:apple_one', 'two:apple_two:word', 'banana', 'there:banana_one:ban', 'there:bana']

st2=list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r"(^[^:]*:)|(:[^:]*$)", "", x), st1))
```

Outputs:

```py
['apple', 'apple_one', 'apple_two', 'banana', 'banana_one', 'bana']
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one liner?

Without the use of any libraries. :)

```
>>> [split[1 if len(split) > 1 else 0] for s in st1 if (split := s.split(':',2))]
['apple', 'apple_one', 'apple_two', 'banana', 'banana_one', 'bana']
```